# How to set scope parameter to read_write on stripe using allauth?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, stripe-connect

I was wondering how I could provide the `scope` parameter set to `read_write` when an user subscribes through **Stripe connect** using **Django-allauth**?

I'm in development mode and when I create an account and try to make a charge on another user's product I get this error :

`Cannot transfer to a destination that is connected with read_only scope.`

I've come across this in the documentation :

> The Stripe endpoint needs to at least receive two parameters:
>
> - response_type, with a value of code.
> - Your client_id.
>
> You’ll likely also want to provide the scope. This parameter dictates
>   what your platform will be able to do on behalf of the connected
>   account. The options are read_write and read_only, with read_only
>   being the default.

But I have no idea on how I could set the scope to read_write ? Anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `settings.py`

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'stripe': {
        'SCOPE': ['read_write']
    }
}
```